# Ubuntu: Kernel 5.6.0-rc3: No IOCTL support in file_operations?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, ioctl

I am using ubuntu and kernel version 5.6.3-rc3.
I don't see any ioctls in the `file_operations` structure in the header.

**Is the support removed? What is the substitute?**

Pasted below from the `linux/fs.h` header.

```c
struct file_operations {
        struct module *owner;
        loff_t (*llseek) (struct file *, loff_t, int);
        ssize_t (*read) (struct file *, char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
        ssize_t (*write) (struct file *, const char __user *, size_t, loff_t *);
        ssize_t (*read_iter) (struct kiocb *, struct iov_iter *);
        ssize_t (*write_iter) (struct kiocb *, struct iov_iter *);
        int (*iopoll)(struct kiocb *kiocb, bool spin);
        int (*iterate) (struct file *, struct dir_context *);
        int (*iterate_shared) (struct file *, struct dir_context *);
        __poll_t (*poll) (struct file *, struct poll_table_struct *);
        long (*unlocked_ioctl) (struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
        long (*compat_ioctl) (struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
        int (*mmap) (struct file *, struct vm_area_struct *);
        unsigned long mmap_supported_flags;
        int (*open) (struct inode *, struct file *);
        int (*flush) (struct file *, fl_owner_t id);
        int (*release) (struct inode *, struct file *);
        int (*fsync) (struct file *, loff_t, loff_t, int datasync);
        int (*fasync) (int, struct file *, int);
        int (*lock) (struct file *, int, struct file_lock *);
        ssize_t (*sendpage) (struct file *, struct page *, int, size_t, loff_t
 unsigned long (*get_unmapped_area)(struct file *, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long);
        int (*check_flags)(int);
        int (*setfl)(struct file *, unsigned long);
        int (*flock) (struct file *, int, struct file_lock *);
        ssize_t (*splice_write)(struct pipe_inode_info *, struct file *, loff_t *, size_t, unsigned int);
        ssize_t (*splice_read)(struct file *, loff_t *, struct pipe_inode_info *, size_t, unsigned int);
        int (*setlease)(struct file *, long, struct file_lock **, void **);
        long (*fallocate)(struct file *file, int mode, loff_t offset,
                          loff_t len);
        void (*show_fdinfo)(struct seq_file *m, struct file *f);
#ifndef CONFIG_MMU
        unsigned (*mmap_capabilities)(struct file *);
#endif
        ssize_t (*copy_file_range)(struct file *, loff_t, struct file *,
                        loff_t, size_t, unsigned int);
        loff_t (*remap_file_range)(struct file *file_in, loff_t pos_in,
                                   struct file *file_out, loff_t pos_out,
                                   loff_t len, unsigned int remap_flags);
        int (*fadvise)(struct file *, loff_t, loff_t, int);
} __randomize_layout;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ioctl()` file operation has been removed since kernel v2.6.36 (a really long time ago).

The "new" way of handling ioctls is through `unlocked_ioctl()` and `compat_ioctl()`, which were introduced in v2.6.11 (2005), and are still present in the latest kernel (and in the code you pasted above):

```c
long (*unlocked_ioctl) (struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
long (*compat_ioctl) (struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
```

Suggested readings:

- [LWN: The new way of `ioctl()`](https://lwn.net/Articles/119652/)
- [`ioctl` removal patchwork](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/cover/205947/)
- [What is the difference between `ioctl()`, `unlocked_ioctl()` and `compat_ioctl()`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4711)